# Access cookies from ASP .NET MVC 3 _Layout View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, cookies, controller

I'm using a default _Layout.cshtml for my layout.

Now, I would like to access the Request object, so I could read the Cookies collection, so I could see if user is logged in. How can I achieve that, since the _Layout view doesn't have a Controller? I thought about creating a model for the _Layout view, but the model can't access Request as well. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9):

Use `@HttpContext.Current.Request`

Comment: Ok. I see I can do it like that :) But, is there any other way, to achive that? To read cookies in a controller-like form and write data to ViewBag for example?

Comment: Didn't understand your question.